# Display XmlDocument (SVG) in WInForm Webbrowser

Tags: xml, vb.net, svg, webbrowser-control

I have created a XmlDocument in my winform application

```
 Public Xdoc As New XmlDocument
```

which contains data for a SVG file. I want to display this SVG file in the webbrowser, but I cant figure out how to.

Can Anybody help me out with this problem?

This is the code I have so far (but it does not do the job)

```
   Public Sub Webbrowerstest()

    Dim text As String = Xdoc.InnerXml
    InitializeComponent()
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = text

    End Sub
```

Edit:
so I modfied my code and I still get an Empty webbrowser control this is the current code I am using: I checked the contents of the Text and Xdoc and the SVG is working if I export it as a file and open it in my normal browser.

```
ublic Sub Webbrowerstest()

    Dim text As String = Xdoc.InnerXml
    InitializeComponent()
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta http-equiv=""x-ua-compatible"" content=""IE=11""><meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8""><title>SVG sample</title> <style type=""text/css""></style></head><body><div>" & text & "</div></body></html>"

End Sub
```

Comment: See : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/displaying-svg-in-web-browsers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you use SVG in a web browser control is the same way you use it in a web browser.

You embed the SVG code inside an svg tag.

Here is some sample HTML code that you could navigate to from a web browser control

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>SVG sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
            Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output :

[image]

Comment: Alright so I editted my code and it still displays and empty webbrowser control for more info look at the edit in the question

Comment: Ok, So I Removed my webbrowser control and added it again now it is working with the code I posted above. only problem is that the SVG is displayed in only a small section of the browers rather than being strechted out over the full surface.